# How to call a method in a UserControl after it is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a multi-paned form, in the left pane is a tree and in the right pane is a Panel.  Tree selections result in specific UserControls being loaded on the Panel.  In this case, since the parent form is always loaded, I cannot hook into the parent form's Shown event.

Most of my UC's have an unbound DataGridView on them which needs to be populated when the UC is created.  There can be 50,000 rows added up front at times, from an SQL Server database.

Up until now I have populated the grids during the UC constructor, but since we started working with 50,000 rows things have changed.  I have found that populating the grid with 50,000 rows from the constructor takes at least 15 minutes for some crazy reason.  However, if I wait to populate the grid until I click a button or from the Load event, it takes 15 seconds.  This is a mystery.  So I am trying to move the loading of the grid elsewhere.

When I try populating the grid from the Load event, however, there are visual inconsistencies.  What happens, is you see a small version of my UC appear, it takes 15 seconds to load the DGV rows, and THEN the UC expands to fill the Panel (the UC Dock property is set to Fill).  So I don't like this option either.

The Shown event would be a perfect place to load my grid, if it existed for UC's.  Does anyone know of another way to do this?

Comment: A better question is why it takes 15 minutes to load in the constructor but 15 seconds elsewhere.

Comment: Probably because his population logic is executing based on something that changes many times during form construction, or he's cache-thrashing loading several DGVs on form load.

Comment: Ideas are welcome as to why this is happening.  I would rather stay with my former approach.  The code consists of a database call (data is not changing) and filling a single DGV.  There is a difference between calling from the constructor and calling from the button - the constructor is being called from inside a BackgroundWorker thread.  Could that be the cause of it?

Comment: I totally agree with Justin. The accepted answer might work for you, but it could bring other troubles. Did you find out why it takes that much longer and/or why the visual inconsistencies happen?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My answer to a similar problem was to populate the DGV when the grid first became visible. This is the essence of lazy-loading; get the information at the last possible second.

Hook into VisibleChanged, which will fire when your control has Show() or Hide() called, or the Visible property manually set. If the field is currently visible, AND the control is not in the process of closing or being disposed (because for some freaky reason controls can become visible in this case), perform your grid population.

Here's the necessary handler, very simple:

```
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnVisibleChanged(e);

    if (Visible && !Disposing) PopulateGridView(); //<-- your population logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this would work for a static sized UC, however when I try it with my UC that Docks "Full" into its container, the grid populates before the UC is resized to fit the container, resulting in some floating-in-mid-air scrollbars for the 15 seconds it takes to load the grid.  I did find a way to load the grid though, by calling a method after the UC is loaded (needed to use ugh DoEvents to get it to draw first!).

Comment: Its close to what I want, but now this load time takes place outside the BackgroundWorker and the GUI becomes less responsive (potential (Not Responding) which I hate).  This may be my best solution though.

Comment: Huh. My UCs with gridviews are also fill-docked. Try using SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout to pause window element positioning until the population is complete. To solve the not-responding problem, you could set up your user control with a delegate and event handler that will interface with an asynchronous populator routine. Have the UC kick off a BeginPopulate method, subscribe to a PopulateComplete event and do its grid-filling work from that handler.

Comment: I have found that the DGV Rows.Add method was causing the problem, but only when called from the constructor.  Instead of calling dgv.Rows.Add(item1, item2, item3); 50,000 times, use dgv.Rows.Add(50000); then work your way down the table and fill in the Cells one row at a time.  This can be called from the constructor and the grid loads just a fast as it should.

Comment: Oh, yeah, don't EVER perform long loops in a form constructor if you want your application to be responsive. I would move the data getting and population into a handle-able event.

Comment: I have multiple user controls which I use "Show()" on to switch between. This solution for me only worked once I manually forced a "control.Visible = false; control.Visible = true;".

Comment: Didn't work... in fact it didn't trigger when loading the custom control, but triggered when it was unloaded, somehow.